# How do you get a license from Marvel comics for game?

Tags: licensing

I want to use Marvel comics character in my game but I don't know how to get Marvel comics character licence for game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is easily findable via Google:

https://www.disneystudiolicensing.com/who-do-i-contact-to-license-content-from-marvel-films/

> Marvel Studios manages the rights to all Marvel Studios produced films only. Iron Man 2008 thru the present slate of films.
>   Request must be sent in writing only to: edenton@marvelstudios.com
>
> Who do I contact to request permission to use Marvel intellectual property for commercial and non-commercial use (including comic books, animated television shows and how to become a licensee).
>   All requests must be submitted in writing to: permissions@marvel.com
>
> Due to the high volume of requests, it can take several weeks for a response.

However as a game developer of many years, I can tell you now that you are unlikely to get permission without a well established publisher backing you, or proof of an extensive track record delivering high quality games.

My advice would be to revisit your game idea and consider if it would still be fun / interesting / saleable if you replaced all of the Marvel characters you wish to license with original characters that you have developed yourself.

Comment: @user115557 if this answer has resolved your question you should [mark it as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)